# Where to find the created file in Android emulator in Windows

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file, android-emulator

I created a simple file write/read app in Eclipse and have successfully tested that it could read what it wrote. The structure is fairly simple. I use FileOutputStream to write a samplefile.txt using openFileOutput and a FileInputStream using openFileInput to read it back. The only minor thing is that I don't know where is the file on my physical hard drive? Can anybody point me to where I could find the file in Windows?

Comment: It will not be in your computer hard disk, you will find it in AVD file explorer.

Comment: go to DDMS and in devices,select your emulator then go to package explorer and find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont give a absolute path the file will be creataed in aplication directory.

This is /data/data/packge-name-of-your-app/

e.g:

/data/data/com.example.test/

See more http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to DDMS perspective, select the emulator which you are using, go to package explorer tag ,then you will get a list of folders hierarchy. 
Go to `/data/data/`
Now you will see a list of packages installed, search for the package name of your app and expand it.
Here you will see the files which your application created when it was running.

P.S : You cannot find this file on the physical drive of your computer,because it is present in the storage of the emulated android virtual device. This storage cannot be directly accessed by you.